# How to use ar_mailer_rails3?

Tags: email, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, newsletter

sorry for my bad english, I'm french.
I'm trying to make a newsletter solution for prestashop, a ruby on rails solution.

To mass mailing, I want to use ar_mailer_rails3 but when I follow instruction from
[Ar_mailer_rails3](https://github.com/yzhang/ar_mailer_rails3)  on git hub, there was an error :

```
ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionmailer-3.0.4/lib/action_mailer/tmail_compat.rb:1: Mail is not a module (TypeError)
```

Does anyone know how to use ar_mailer_rails3 or has already solved this problem ?

Thank you for reply

Comment: Someone have just an example of code or a way to use ar_mailer_rails3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mail is an already exists class, your model name conflicts it
you should rename your ar_mailer_rails model, may be the default "Email" is OK, or use "Notifier" in the example

Comment: Thanks ;) But a few months too late ^ ^